# Is it possible with TFS Aggregator to dinamically change the label of a TAB in workitem form?

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

I'm using TFS 2017 update 1 on premises with still old form layout. Since in my custom workitem type I have more than one Description TAB (e.g. Trigger tab, Pre-conditions tab etc.), I'd like to dynamically change the label of TABS when some tetx is written inside (e.g. adding a * as suffix to the label) in order to give TFS users the possibility to immediately know which TAB effectively contains informations without the need to open them all.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems more related to the useage of a software/extension--*tfs-aggregator*.

Have noticed you also asked the same question in GitHub and already got a reply.

> **No this is not possible with the tfs Aggregator.**
>
> https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/issues/237

Your requirement is also could not be achieved in TFS with workitem customization for now.

---

*Besides, questions about general computing software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Your could ask the question directly under the extension in marketplace or from GitHub.*